# .JQuery .ajax how do I call WCF method with return value?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf

I have been able to call WCF methods with .ajax. How do I call a method that returns a value? I need to call this method to see if data is ready and if not wait one second. The WCF method is:

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        public bool IsDataReady(string requestGUID)
        {
            if (Global.publicDataDictionary.Keys.Contains(requestGUID))
                return true;
            else return false;
        }
```

My JavaScript so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var input = {requestGUID:"<%=guid %>"};
            console.log(input);

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/IsDataReady",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: input,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {

                }
            });
```

EDIT2: I broke out the 2nd ajax call into a method but my logging is showing that the call to 2nd web service never passes a requestGUID. Can't i use the same input variable?

```
   var guid = "<%= this.guid%>";
        // var input = '{"SbiId":"' + guid + '"}';
        // var input = {requestGUID:"ca222cf7-be5e-431a-ab93-9a31e8ae2f4a"};

        function callUpdateGrid(input) {
            console.log(input);
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/GetContactsDataAndCountbyGUID",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: input,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var mtv = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                                console.log(data);
                                mtv.set_dataSource(data.d.Data);
                                mtv.dataBind();
                            }
            });
        }


        function CallIsDataReady(input) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/IsDataReady",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: input,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data) {
                        setTimeout(function (inputInner) { CallIsDataReady(inputInner); }, 1000);
                    }
                    else {
                        //Continue as data is ready
                        callUpdateGrid(input);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var input = { requestGUID: "<%=guid %>" };

            CallIsDataReady(input);

        });
```

EDIT2: I broke out the 2nd ajax call into a method but my logging is showing that the call to 2nd web service is never getting called:

```
url: "http://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/GetContactsDataAndCountbyGUID",

else {
                            //Continue as data is ready
                            callUpdateGrid(input);
                        }
```

Comment: Did you get into `success`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value will be contained in the data parameter passed to the success callback setup in your ajax call.

You will need to check the value here, then if false, setup a timeout, which on expiry will attempt the ajax call again.

It would be best IMO to wrap up the Ajax call inside a function, that you can call in a recursive fashion when the timeout has expired.  e.g.

```
    function CallIsDataReady(input){
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/IsDataReady",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: input,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                if (!data){
                    setTimeout(function(){CallIsDataReady(input);}, 1000);
                }
                else{
                  //Continue as data is ready
                }
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var input = {requestGUID:"<%=guid %>"};
        console.log(input);

        CallIsDataReady(input);
    });
```

Comment: I can't get it working. I think it's my second .ajax call repeating the same name of parameters. I'm going to update my question

Comment: I broke it out into a function to make the 2nd AJAX call and made your change but it still doesn't work. I'll edit.

Comment: Any idea why?  Have you debugged?

Comment: The code is not local but on a server so I can't debug it. But I did use the IE DEv Tools and set breakpoint on callUpdateGrid but I can't get it to hit.

Comment: My logging shows that the second fuction and 2nd AJAX call never get a requestGUID value. Can't I call the 2nd function with the same input value?

Comment: My logging shows the 2nd AJAX call http://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/GetContactsDataAndCountbyGUID" is never happening

Answer (score 0):

When you view source on this page is:

```
var input = {requestGUID:"<%=guid %>"};
```

showing correctly in the javascript?  If you put a breakpoint in your IsDataReady method, do you see if `requestGUID` has a value?  Is your service on the same domain as the page calling it?

EDIT:
In your service change: `[WebGet]`
to:

```
[WebGet(
RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json]
```

Read up on RESTful web services:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

Comment: I see my IsDataReady returning what looks to be XML even though the service is an JSON service and the .ajax call is set for JSOn <boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">true</boolean>