# jQuery .ajax call never calling method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf

In this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22509519/jquery-ajax-how-do-i-call-wcf-method-with-return-value) I learned how to get a return value from an AJAX call:

```
function CallIsDataReady(input) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/IsDataReady",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: input,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data) {
                        setTimeout(function (inputInner) { CallIsDataReady(inputInner); }, 1000);
                    }
                    else {
                        //Continue as data is ready
                        callUpdateGrid(input);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var input = { requestGUID: "<%=guid %>" };

            CallIsDataReady(input);

        });
```

This function calls its web service wich does return true. The problem is that inside the following callUpdateGrid, the logging shows that that web service method is not getting called from the $.ajax call:

```
function callUpdateGrid(input) {
    console.log(input);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/GetContactsDataAndCountbyGUID",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: input,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var mtv = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                        console.log(data);
                        mtv.set_dataSource(data.d.Data);
                        mtv.dataBind();
                    }
    });
}
```

Anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: In the top function, you have `callUpdateGrid(input)` - shouldn't that be `callUpdateGrid(data)` ??

Comment: Isn't data the true/false value returned by first call?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling the function else {
                        //Continue as data is ready
                        callUpdateGrid(input);
                    }

Comment: OK, well, you're going to have to use the developer console to figure out exactly what HTTP transactions are taking place and what the responses look like. You have not described what exactly that `console.log()` call actually prints, or if you have I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *always* a good idea to include an error handler function as one of the options passed to $.ajax. For example, add this code after your success functions:

```
    ,
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errThrown) {
        console.log("AJAX call failed");
        console.log(errThrown);
    }
```

That will log at least a bit of information if the $.ajax call doesn't succeed.

**EDIT**
According to your comment, this logs
`SyntaxError: Invalid character`

And in fact, I now see that you are giving a plain JavaScript object as the `data` option passed to $.ajax, but indicating that it is a JSON object in the `dataType` field. You need to actually convert the input object into JSON yourself, like so:

```
    data: JSON.stringify(input),
    dataType: 'json',
```

Alternatively, you could simply format `input` as a JSON object in first place, like so:

```
var input = { "requestGUID": "<%=guid %>" };
```

The quotes around the field name `requestGUID` are sufficient, in this case, to give you a JSON object.

Comment: AJAX call failed   SyntaxError: Invalid character That is in CallDataIsReady

Comment: It must be on the callUpdateGrid because logging confirms the first web call is called and succeeds with true.

Comment: I changed to var input = { "requestGUID": "<%=guid %>" }; and I get the same exact error

Comment: I've got the same error and it's ever calling the 2nd function