# Syntax Error: Invalid character in jQuery $.ajax call where?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wcf

I have the following bit of jQuery calling a WCF method. The method call succeeds to the extent that I can see it logging and it *does* return a Boolean true. However, the error handler is coming back with "AJAX call failed in CallIsDataReady" and "Syntax Error: Invalid character." It then does not take the success path call the callUpdateGrid. I can't find the Invalid character. Help!

```
function CallIsDataReady(input) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/IsDataReady",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: input,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data) {
                        setTimeout(function (inputInner) { CallIsDataReady(inputInner); }, 1000);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("data returned - calling callUpDateGrid");
                        //Continue as data is ready
                        callUpdateGrid(input);
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errThrown) {
                    console.log("AJAX call failed in CallIsDataReady");
                    console.log(errThrown);
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var input = { "requestGUID": "<%=guid %>" };

            CallIsDataReady(input);

        });
```

Server side method returns JSON as it is an AJAX enabled Web service:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        public bool IsDataReady(string requestGUID)
        {
            bool isReady = Global.publicDataDictionary.Keys.Contains(requestGUID);

            using (savitasEntities2 db = new savitasEntities2())
            {
                DataRequestLog drl = new DataRequestLog();
                drl.registrationID = "";
                drl.request = "Is Ready=" + isReady;
                drl.connectionID = "";
                drl.created = System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
                drl.direction = "tickler";
                drl.dataRequestGUID = requestGUID;
                db.DataRequestLogs.Add(drl);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return isReady;
        }
```

EDIT: the 2nd JavaScript method is:

```
 function callUpdateGrid(input) {
            console.log(input);
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/GetContactsDataAndCountbyGUID",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: input,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var mtv = $find("<%= RadGrid1.ClientID %>").get_masterTableView();
                                console.log(data);
                                mtv.set_dataSource(data.d.Data);
                                mtv.dataBind();
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errThrown) {
                    console.log("AJAX call failed in callUpdateGrid");
                    console.log(errThrown);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like you are not returning JSON back from the server

Comment: `JSON.parse` also throws syntax errors when the JSON is invalid. Could this be the cause?

Comment: If you're just returning a boolean, remove the dataType parameter.

Comment: I had an error - And in fact, I now see that you are giving a plain JavaScript object as the data option passed to $.ajax, but indicating that it is a JSON object in the dataType field but that was fixed by making this a JSON object  var input = { "requestGUID": "<%=guid %>" };

Comment: The dataType has nothing to do with what you send, it's the dataformat of the response you expect to get back.

Comment: Yes, see my edit, I'm getting back JSON.

Comment: I don't really know any WCF, but isReady looks like a boolean to me ?

Comment: Why don't you post the exact response from the server? You can get it from the network panel of the developer tools in any browswer you're using. This way we can see whether you're receiving valid JSON or not.

Comment: @user2471435 It looks like not, you are returning a boolean, not any object using JSON notation. And it's quite confusing, have you fixed your issue or still get same error???

Comment: I guess it's not returning HJSON. Fiddler shows: <boolean xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">false</boolean>

Comment: ^^^ It should be pretty easy to just remove the line with the dataType, and see if it works, instead of arguing about wether or not it's valid JSON ?

Comment: @adeneo I'm quite sure you are correct! Removing dataType would fix OP issue

Comment: @A.Wolff - Maybe, time will tell !

Comment: Ok, II removed the dataType and it works and now calls the 2nd function which probably has same problem? Writes "data returned calling CallUpDateGrid" where it has an ivalid character too, I'll edit my post

Comment: URL returns XML, not JSON. I don't really understand why you are focused on JSON when none of your WCF methods seem to return it

Comment: The problem now is that my 2nd function is not getting an input when I call it: callUpdateGrid(input); It should be like var input = { "requestGUID": "<%=guid %>" }

Comment: Ok, commented out 2nd dataType and debugger blows on mtv.set_dataSource(data.d.Data); saying "Unable to get property "Data" of undefined or null reference

Comment: Why you have re-posted it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513513/jquery-ajax-call-never-calling-method

Answer (score 0):

As you have got your code working but still you should consider these things in mind. I am not expert in JavaScript but I believe that the way you are calling method is incorrect. First of all, your `OperationContract` is `WebGet`, so you don't need to provide `Content-Type` in your request. `Content-Type` is normally used when you are sending large amount of data using **POST** method. So, according to me, change following:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GUID={requestGUID}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public bool IsDataReady(string requestGUID)
{
    bool isReady = Global.publicDataDictionary.Keys.Contains(requestGUID);
    using (savitasEntities2 db = new savitasEntities2())
    {
        DataRequestLog drl = new DataRequestLog();
        drl.registrationID = "";
        drl.request = "Is Ready=" + isReady;
        drl.connectionID = "";
        drl.created = System.DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        drl.direction = "tickler";
        drl.dataRequestGUID = requestGUID;
        db.DataRequestLogs.Add(drl);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    return isReady;
}
```

I hope that this will definitely work. Now this method will return `isReady` in JSON format. If you do not specify `ResponseFormat` in your `OperationContract`, then by default it will be returned into `XML`.

Now try removing `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` as you are not sending data in **JSON** and execute your method. Response will be in JSON format, so, you have to  parse it to get the `isReady` value.

Use this URL to call service:

```
url: "http://www.blah.com/services/TestsService.svc/GUID=abc123"
```

This is simple and easily implementable. Thanks for your patience.

**EDIT:** Add `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare` in your `OperatcionContract`.