# How do I get JavaScript setTimeout to stop after 10 tries?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following part of a jQuery .ajax call. It checks every second I believe. How can I get to stop after 10 tries?

```
 success: function (data) {
                    if (!data) {
                        setTimeout(function (inputInner) { CallIsDataReady(inputInner); }, 1000);
                    }
```

EDIT: I implemented one solution but the logging for the service call seems to stop after 2 times.

```
function CallIsDataReady(input) {
            var timer;
            var count = 0;

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.example.com/services/TestsService.svc/IsDataReady",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: input,
                // dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (!data) {
                        setTimeout(function(inputInner) {
                            CallIsDataReady(inputInner);
                            count++;
                            if (count == 10) {
                                clearInterval(timer);
                                count = 0;
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("data returned - calling callUpDateGrid");
                        //Continue as data is ready
                        callUpdateGrid(input);
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errThrown) {
                    console.log("AJAX call failed in CallIsDataReady");
                    console.log(errThrown);
                }
            });
```

Comment: it doesn't check every second. you need to use `setInterval` for that. this just runs the function body once after the specified interval

Comment: Can you show me the code to do this?

Comment: @user2471435: See the documentation.

Comment: @anurupr: `CallIsDataReady` is probably  the function that makes the AJAX call, so it's (sort of) recursive.,

Comment: @anurupr: Well, I did say "probably", didn't I? However, the question isn't about making it run over and over, but rather about making it stop running after 10 tries, so I'd say its a safe assumption. *"...It checks every second I believe. How can I get to stop after 10 tries?"*

Comment: @user2471435: You need to post your full function. If it is what it seems, most of the solutions below will be wrong.

Comment: @anurupr: Look at his [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515905/syntax-error-invalid-character-in-jquery-ajax-call-where). That's exactly what's happening. So it *does* check every second, just like the question describes, or at least with a 1 second buffer after the previous response.

Comment: WRT your update, your `count` is inside `CallIsDataReady()`, which means it starts at `0` with every call. You need to put it outside the function, so that all the calls to `CallIsDataReady()` will share it, and observe its changes.

Comment: ...also, `clearInterval` won't do anything with a `setTimeout` id. I think you're taking bits and pieces of the answers below, and combining them. What you need to do is make the recursive call to `CallIsDataReady()` conditional on the `count`. There's nothing preventing the call right now.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign your setTimeout to a variable, and use a counter, when it reaches 10, call clearTimeout()

Comment: Can you show me the code please? I don't know JS well.

Answer (score 1):

user setInterval with a counter:

```
if (!data) {
    var count = 0;
    var interval;
    interval = setInterval(function (inputInner) {
        if (count === 10) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }
        CallIsDataReady(inputInner);
        count++;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Since the code already repeats every second, you're now starting a new interval with every call. And if the `CallIsDataReady()` is recursive *(as seems to be the case)*, the number of calls will increase exponentially.

Comment: @cookiemonster, thanks, edited my code. Does it look okay now?

Comment: No, the problem is that `CallIsDataReady()` actually invokes the function that invokes the `$.ajax` call that is shown in the question (now updated). So the first time, there's the one call. If you then start an interval, it's going to invoke it again, and start its own interval, so now there's two intervals running. After another second, both of those will make a recursive call, starting two more, so now there's four, then eight, then sixteen, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

```
  // global variable - should be outside your ajax function
 var timer;
 var count = 0;

 ....
 success : function( data) {
               if( ! data ) {
                  // don't know where you are getting inputInner. assuming its a global variable
                  timer = setInterval ( function ( inputInner ) { 
                                            CallIsDataReady(inputInner);
                                            count++; 
                                            if ( count == 10 ) { 
                                              clearInterval(timer); 
                                              count = 0;
                                            }  
                                        }, 1000);
                }
           }
```

Comment: I implemented this in the AJAX call and the logging seems to indicate that it stops after two. I'll update the post above.

Answer (score 0):

Use an interval

```
var count = 0,
    handler = setInterval(dostuff, 1000);

function dostuff(inputInner){

   //CallIsDataReady(inputInner);

   if(++count === 10)
       clearInterval(handler);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mGgLz/

However, you should never rely on the assumption that the ajax call always takes < 1000ms. Check the `readyState` on the XHR and make sure it's 4 before polling again.